# Not sure where to put my delete function without getting a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic-programming, new-operator, delete-operator

I have an object MyObject with member variables that hold a name (which is what the overloaded constructor sets and a linked list of character data. I read in from a file that has a bunch of MyObjects in the following format:

```
name,a,b,c,d
name1,a,b,c,d,e
// etc.
```

My code is supposed to grab each object and add it to myVect
`vector<MyObject*> myVect;`

My problem is that I use new to allocate. Of course I know this means I need delete (and when I don't have delete there are memory leaks so I don't think this a double deletion issue), but no matter where I delete ptr, it cause a segmentation fault.

I would love for myVect to not hold pointers but it has to (assignment).

Here's the code

```
void Sequencer::ReadFile() {
  ifstream fin;
  fin.open(fileName);
  cout << "Opened File" << endl;
  string line = "";
  MyObject* ptr;
  while(getline(fin, line)) {
    string name = "";
    int count = 0;
    while(line[count] != ',') {
      name += line[count];
      count++;
    }
    ptr = new MyObject(name);
    for(int i = count + 1; i < line.size(); i+=2) {
      (*ptr).InsertEnd(line[i]);
    }
    myVect.push_back(ptr);
    //delete ptr;                                                               
    //ptr = nullptr;                                                            
  }
  //delete ptr;                                                                 
  //ptr = nullptr;                                                              
  fin.close();
}
```

Comment: You put it wherever `myVect` goes out of scope.  Probably `Sequencer`'s destructor.

Comment: So like ... Sequencer::~Sequencer() {
  delete ptr;
}

Comment: No, if `m_DNA` and `m_RNA` contain pointers to dynamically-allocated objects you will need to loop through them and `delete` each object.  Or use vectors of smart pointers and let the smart pointers `delete` the objects when the vectors die.

Comment: So `~Sequencer() { // the loops would be here }` should have 2 for loops. Where the loops `delete m_DNA[i]` and `delete m_mRNA[i]` @MilesBudnek

Answer (score 1):

Remember, you do not `delete` pointers, you `delete` the thing a pointer points to.  That means that it doesn't make sense to `delete ptr` anywhere in `ReadFile`, since you want the pointed-to objects to continue to exist for as long as `myVect` holds pointers to them.

Instead you want to `delete` each object pointed to by the pointers in `myVect` whenever you're finished with them.  The most common place for that is in the destructor of the object that `myVect` is a member of.  For example:

```
Sequencer::~Sequencer() {
    for (MyObject* p : myVect) {
        delete p;
    }
}
```

---

Of course, if you just used smart pointers instead of raw pointers then you wouldn't need to manually `delete` anything.  For instance, `myVect` could be a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyOjbect>>`.  In that case the `unique_ptr`s would automatically `delete` the object they point to when their lifetime ends.

In that case you would change `ReadFile` to something like this:

```
void Sequencer::ReadFile() {
  std::ifstream fin(fileName);
  std::string line = "";
  while(std::getline(fin, line)) {
    std::string name = "";
    int count = 0;
    while(line[count] != ',') {
      name += line[count];
      count++;
    }
    std::unique_ptr<MyObject> ptr = std::make_unique<MyObject>(name);
    for(int i = count + 1; i < line.size(); i+=2) {
      ptr->InsertEnd(line[i]);
    }
    myVect.push_back(ptr);
  }
}
```

---

That's all assuming you need pointers at all.  Your current `ReadFile` implementation doesn't have any particular reason to dynamically allocate objects.  If possible, the best solution would be to just have `myVect` be a `std::vector<MyObject>` and let `std::vector` handle all of the objects' lifetimes itself:

```
void Sequencer::ReadFile() {
  std::ifstream fin(fileName);
  std::string line = "";
  while(std::getline(fin, line)) {
    std::string name = "";
    int count = 0;
    while(line[count] != ',') {
      name += line[count];
      count++;
    }
    MyObject obj(name);
    for(int i = count + 1; i < line.size(); i+=2) {
      obj.InsertEnd(line[i]);
    }
    myVect.push_back(obj);
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to use smart pointers or change the way myVect is declared (ugh). Just to clarify your first point ... I leave `ReadFile` as it was the way I posted it and then just change the destructor to what you said. I did that and the program compiles and runs just fine but it didn't fix the memory leaks. The destructor is called automatically right?

Comment: Yes, an object's destructor runs automatically whenever the object's lifetime ends.  Does whatever owns your `Sequencer` perhaps not delete it correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by what "owns" `Sequencer`

Comment: If you mean the code that creates a Sequencer then I suppose it's possible but I doubt it because that was starter code that was provided for us. Sorry I'm kind of slow. I appreciate your help though.

Comment: A resource's "owner" is the thing that is responsible for deleting/freeing that resource.  For instance, in this instance a `Sequencer` object "owns` the objects pointed to by the pointers contained in `myVect`.  Sadly there's not enough here to offer much more advice.  You should either edit your question or ask a new question with a [mcve] if you need more specific answer.